# Optinimizing query with fts + composite index

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, query-optimization, query-performance

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
    structural_type=1 
    AND parent_id='167F2-F' 
    AND points_to_id=''
    # AND match(search) against ('donotmatch124213123123')
```

The search takes about 10ms to run, running on the composite index (structural_type, parent_id, points_to_id). However, when I add in the fts index, the query balloons to taking ~1s, regardless of what is contained in the match criteria. Basically it seems like it 'skips the index' whenever I have a fts search applied.

What would be the best way to optimize this query?

**Update**: a few explains:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT... # without fts

id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  table   NULL    ref structural_type structural_type 209 const,const,const   2   100.00  NULL
```

With fts (also adding 'force index'):

```
explain SELECT ... force INDEX (structural_type) AND match...

id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  table   NULL    fulltext    structural_type,search  search  0   const   1   5.00    Using where; Ft_hints: sorted
```

The only thing I can think of which would be incredibly hack-ish, would be to add an additional term to the fts so it does the filter 'within' that. For example:

```
fts_term = fts_term += " StructuralType1ParentID167F2FPointsToID"
```

Comment: How many results are returned by the commented version of the query?

Comment: @BenoitEsnard 2 results. Table size is 2.4m.

Comment: Would you consider using an optimizer hint to make it consider only the non-fts index?

Comment: @BillKarwin I tried using `force INDEX (structural_type)` but still get the wrong index. I'll put that in the question too...

Comment: @BillKarwin -- updated with explain plans

Comment: @David542: have you run a `OPTIMIZE TABLE` query on the table?

Comment: @BenoitEsnard -- no, could you please explain what that would do (is that like a vacuum command?)

Comment: The documentation suggests that index hints are ignored when you use fulltext search in natural language mode, but the index hint is honored when you use boolean mode. Can you try testing your fulltext search in boolean mode?

Comment: @BillKarwin sure I'll test that -- what is the difference between the two modes?

Comment: @David542: MySQL keeps internal stats about the table data, to estimate which index should be used for a query. Those stats might be inaccurate if the table data has changed a lot. Regenerating the stats might help MySQL to choose the right index here.

Comment: The different modes use different syntax for the search expression, and the result of the expression returns different values. I'd rather refer you to documentation than type it all in: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @BenoitEsnard -- honestly, for whatever reason, your solution worked. It decreased almost all fts queries by about 80%. Do you happen to know why the fts index seems to degrade so much over time?

Comment: I'm from a PostgreSQL background, so I'm not sure how MySQL internals really work here. In PostgreSQL, you need some maintenance on your table (the data stats, in your case), so I guess it's the same here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL optimizer can only use one index for your WHERE clause, so it has to choose between the composite one and the FULLTEXT one.

Since it can't run both queries to bench which one is faster, it will estimate how fast will different execution plans be.

To do so, MySQL uses some internal stats it keeps about each table. But those stats can be very different from the reality if they aren't updated and the data changes in the table.

Running a `OPTIMIZE TABLE table` query allows MySQL to refresh its table stats, so it will be able to perform better estimates and choose the better index.

Answer (score 0):

Try expressing this without the full text logic, using `like`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE structural_type = 1 AND
      parent_id  ='167F2-F' AND
      points_to_id = '' AND
      search not like '%donotmatch124213123123%';
```

The index should still be used for the first three columns.  `LIKE` might be slow, but if not many rows match the first three, this might not be as bad as using the full text index.

Comment: that's a possible solution, though in my question I haven't included multiple terms, and in other queries I may need to use multiple terms in the fts index.

Comment: @David542 . . . If this has better performance, you can try using a regular expression.